# "Position: fixed" in CSS changes "justify-content-end"

Tags: html, css, nav, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with the content on the right of the page. This worked until I added position:fixed in CSS. After I added position:fixed, the content got relocated to the left of the page. Can someone tell me why this happened?

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link active" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li> <a data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

position: fixed; =
"Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page..." (source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=control)

Not sure what you want the final outcome to be, but check out your other positioning options: static, relative, absolute, fixed, sticky.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The OP wanted it on the right _I'm trying to make a navigation bar with the content on the right of the page._

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=control

> **Fixed:** Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. [...]

The specified position by default will be at the top/left of the screen without any additional positioning in the CSS. To move it around, use the `top left right bottom` properties. To move it to the right, specify a value for `right` that matches the distance you want the menu to be from the right side of the page.

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em; right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link active" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li> <a data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `right: 0px` to the header css (or however many pixels from the edge you want it).

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link active" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li> <a data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```